# Why's is Rails giving me an error about the 'create' action not being in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I press new on my Jobs form in seeing an error that it could not find 'create' in my JobsController.

```
Unknown action

The action 'create' could not be found for JobsController
```

Here' my controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  private
  def load_clients
        @clients = collection_select :client, :client_id
  end

  def index
    @job = Job.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(params[:job])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @job, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @job }
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see. It' clearly there. Why is Rails not seeing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you assign the create method as private.

Try redefine your controller this way.

Here' my controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  def show
    ...
  end

  private

  def load_clients
    @clients = collection_select :client, :client_id
  end

end
```